# Android Studio 3.0 not able to import google play service even it is added in build.gradle file

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to fetch device current location but when i am trying to imported Location Service it. But it show can not resolve symbol LocationService

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

[image: importing location service]

Build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-beta1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

I have tried with google play services previous version (11.4.2) as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile play-services-location.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Importing below dependencies might help you.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.0.1'
```

Please check once. (Make sure you use latest dependencies).
Below link might help you to do the same.
http://gradleplease.appspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have to add play location service dependency as well.

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+'
```